# Is $x^0$ polynominal??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, polynomials

I wanted to know if the function $f(x)=x^0$ is a polynomial

There is a gap at $x=0$ as $0^0$ is indeterminate

But $0^0$ is indeterminate because $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} x^0 = 1$

but $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} 0^x = 0$

but in my case I think I determined the case to follow ($x^0$), So should the function be undefined at zero and be not a polynomial by convention that $0^0$ is undetermined

or consider $0^0 = 1$ and with it $f(x)$ a polynomial

Comment: $0^0=1{{{{}}}}$.

Comment: Yes. $x^0$ is a polynomial. It is the same polynomial as $1$. Limits have nothing to do with it, but you do need to study algebra a bit more to get to the core of the matter. You see, in algebra polynomials are not really functions at all.  But, to come up with a situation where the difference between *polynomials* and *polynomial functions* is clearly visible, you need to leave the realm of real numbers.

Comment: You need to draw a distinction between polynomial (formal expression) and polynomial function (function obtained by evaluating a polynomial at each given point). And as polynomial, $x^0$ is defined as the polynomial $1$,

Comment: $x^0$ is $1$, like every product of $0$ factors ($0!$ would be another example). There is no gap.

Comment: @Lord Why is that so? Please excuse me I do not think so.

Comment: @akhmeteni Because that makes the function $f(x)=x^0$ the same as $g(x)=1$ (that is we can always write polynomial as $\sum c_kx^k$ and also evaluate them at $x=0$ with the intented result). There are other reasons, but basically it's because it's convenient in many situation to define $0^0=1$.

Comment: @akhmeteni, We may either define $0^0 = 1$ and claim that the function $(x, y) \mapsto x^y$ has discontinuity at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ or simply declare that this function is not defined here. Either way is acceptable as long as its meaning is clarified in the context (and useful).

Comment: Ok it may be convenient, but I was taught that $0^0$ is not well defined, like division by zero. But as you say, I understand the motive.

Comment: Indeterminate is not the same as undefined. $x^y$ has no continuous value at $(0,0)$ but surely $x^0$ has a continuous value at $x=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is a polynomial. In the context of Algebra, $x^0$ is the same thing as the constant polynomial $1$.